# Fix PHP port 34543 Issue

Tags: php, mysql, phpbb, osx-server

I've been setting up a phpbb forum, and have been encountering a bug in many of the page redirects.  When someone logs in, for example, it goes to this: 
`your domain.com:34543/index.php?sid=6bcf305366b67a83a882c2323d9ee967.`  
When I delete the :`34543`, it loads just fine.  How do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: What does your site configuration (config.php) look like (taking out database config strings, etc.)? Can you update your post with that?

Comment: this must be a port configuration issue, you have to define that this is the default port

Comment: @CDrosos So the default port needs to be 34543?

Comment: @samlev I can't get to it right now, as I'm on another network right now, but I will tell you as soon as I have access to it.

Comment: `<?php
// phpBB 3.1.x auto-generated configuration file
// Do not change anything in this file!
$dbms = 'phpbb\\db\\driver\\mysql';
$dbhost = '127.0.0.1';
$dbport = '3306';
$dbname = 'phpbb_forum'; 'code'
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpasswd = 'I won't give the password';
$table_prefix = 'phpbb_';
$phpbb_adm_relative_path = 'adm/';
$acm_type = 'phpbb\\cache\\driver\\file';

@define('PHPBB_INSTALLED', true);
// @define('PHPBB_DISPLAY_LOAD_TIME', true);
// @define('DEBUG', true);
// @define('DEBUG_CONTAINER', true); `

Comment: So I figured what the problem is.  It's OS X server.  Some reason the Apache server is running through port 34543 instead of 443 and 80.  Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score -1):

Go into /Library/Server/Web/Config/apache2/sites/ and open the 0000_127.0.0.1_34543_.conf in TextEdit. In my case, I'm using Xcode. Change `<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:34543>` to `<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>`
Also note: you must enable permissions with an admin account. To do this, right click on the folder and choose get info. Scroll to the bottom and click the lock to authenticate. In permissions change read only to read and write. Do this for the files, too.

EDIT:

I forgot to add that you need to restart web services in order for the fix to take effect.  I'm sorry to the people that I lead wrong, as I was distracted while writing this.

Note:

You will need to do this for every time that you update server.
It is also a good idea to do this with the .default file, too

Comment: This at least worked for me. I don't know about anyone else